# QMainWindow no longer active window

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm making a simple game with Qt and I'd like to pause the game when the user switches to a different window (this could be by minimizing it or by accidentally clicking on a window beside it, etc).  My game is wrapped in a QMainWindow, so I'd like to be able to detect when that loses focus.

I've tried a few different methods for this, but I haven't been successful.  I first tried overloading QMainWindow's focusOutEvent, but this method was only called when I first gave the window focus with setFocus.  I also tried to overload the window's event(QEvent *) method to check for QEvent::ApplicationActive and QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate.

I would post the code for my QMainWindow but there isn't much to show, I literally just tried to implement those two methods but neither were called.  I did nothing else to set up those methods (maybe I'm missing a step?).

Does anyone know a good way to determine if your QMainWindow has "lost focus"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar need once, and resolved it by overloading `event(QEvent*)` method of my QMainWindow :

```
bool MyMainWindow::event(QEvent * e)
{
    switch(e->type())
    {
        // ...

        case QEvent::WindowActivate :
            // gained focus
            break ;

        case QEvent::WindowDeactivate :
            // lost focus
            break ;
        // ...
    } ;
    return QMainWindow::event(e) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent) -

> A widget normally must `setFocusPolicy()` to something other than
>   Qt::NoFocus in order to receive focus events. (Note that the
>   application programmer can call `setFocus()` on any widget, even those
>   that do not normally accept focus.)

From this part of the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop), about `focusPolicy`-

> This property holds the way the widget accepts keyboard focus.
>
> The policy is `Qt::TabFocus` if the widget accepts keyboard focus by
>   tabbing, `Qt::ClickFocus` if the widget accepts focus by clicking,
>   `Qt::StrongFocus` if it accepts both, and `Qt::NoFocus` (the default) if
>   it does not accept focus at all.
>
> You must enable keyboard focus for a widget if it processes keyboard
>   events. This is normally done from the widget's constructor. For
>   instance, the `QLineEdit` constructor calls
>   `setFocusPolicy`(`Qt::StrongFocus`).

So set your focus policies accordingly, I guess then you will receive appropriate focus events.

Answer (score 0):

Try `QWidget::isActiveWindow()` .